# Maximum possible number of iterations of while loop

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

[image]

My answer is `46`(don't remember how I got it). I took an array in descending order, and simulated it.

Source: GATE-CS 2016 question

Comment: I find this straining to read: can you be bothered to type it in? (use block-quote). What is the connection between the array you took and the picture you present?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because just asking for confirmation in this way is not an interesting question.

Comment: @starblue: the OP isn't just asking for a confirmation. On the other hand, he is deemed to show the effort he made, which he did. The question doesn't look trivial, so I don't support the downvotes.

Comment: By empirical observation, the maximum number of operations for N numbers is N² (and the minimum is N).

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not CS homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sorting device.

It rotates the queue (via the stack) until the smallest element is pushed to the stack. Then, the smallest element remains there.

This process continues with the remaining N-1 elements, and so on.

If the queue is initially sorted, the loop is executed just N times.

If the queue is initially sorted in the decreasing order, the loop is executed 2N-1 + 2N-3 + ... + 1 = N² times, and this is the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this program in java I get 256 for array in descending order.

```
    int count=0;
    int[] q = new int[] {16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    for(int a : q)
    {
        queue.add(a);
    }
    while(!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.peek() <= queue.peek())
        {
            Integer x=queue.remove();   
            stack.push(x);
        }
        else
        {
            Integer x=stack.pop();
            queue.add(x);
        }
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```